# Watch YouTube without suggestions and ads on IPad

Tags: ios

In desktop browsers I have extensions for that. But iOS browsers don't support extensions. So is it even possible?

**EDIT:** Also, is it possible to get rid of "recommendations", i.e. videos on home page and sidebar? I would like to watch only channels I am subscribed, but sometimes I am too weak and cann't struggle against temptation to watch "recommended" stuff which leads to lots of wasted time. On desktop I have empty home page and no sidebar thanks to browser extension so I see only videos I need on subscribed channels. Is it possible on iPad?

Comment: Yes - find the CSS tag that the extension blocks on the desktop and program that in to 1Blocker. I do that here on Ask Different  to remove things - I’ll add to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (sometimes - and no, sometimes). Nothing will be able to block everything Google and YouTube throws at you long term. Short term, you can very likely get excellent relief from some and perhaps all that irritates you or erodes your privacy while you consume their content and avoid their advertising.

iOS has content blockers that work equivalently to an extension, but differently than extension due to OS architecture.

Since iOS is sandboxed and inter-app communication and code injection are much more restricted than on macOS, you’ll want to try a few of the commercially available blockers and perhaps try your hand at writing one if you are so inclined. It’s free to write these with Xcode and install your app on your device.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/creating_a_content_blocker

I use FireFox rarely on iOS and I pay for and benefit greatly from OneBlocker. Brave browser is great. Lastly, consider removing google as your search engine on every last device in your home network. Use Duck Duck Go for a while and you’ll see less targeted advertisements. You may or may not like that, tbh, but over time it can help immensely without resorting to something like https://pi-hole.net/ .

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/1blocker-for-safari/id1365531024
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/brave-private-web-browser/id1052879175
- https://DuckDuckGo.com

It does a marvelous job on YouTube as does adding the request for no cookies to the URL for YouTube. Just keep in mind, google makes billions in getting you to see their ads, so it’s a bit of an arms race between people attempting to block and people attempting to track. The reality is the ***Surveillance-Advertising Complex*** is massively funded and has hired some of the best software minds of a generation to track you and boost their revenue. Until and unless regulation or cultural shift alters the balance of google, It will neither be easy nor completely effective to escape all of their efforts - but that doesn’t mean [we shouldn’t try](https://duckduckgo.com/spread).

- https://youtube-nocookies.com
- https://www.cnet.com/news/youtubes-new-nocookie-feature-continues-to-serve-cookies/

---

Since you edited in some very specific information - here’s how I block hot network questions from the side bar here on iOS using 1Blocker. You can very well do the same in YouTube if you find the tag they use to serve sidebar ads. The developer of the extension you use might help you if you can’t figure out what they did, there.

[image: CSS blocking in 1Blocker]

Comment: And yes, I know I dredged up ancient internet history with the flash no cookie links at the end. This really is a complicated mix of cultural, organizational and monetization, privacy, regulation and innovation based systems colliding in a mess of “what code shipped to you when you click the same link as I do”.

Comment: It is funny fact that single indie developer can at least partially counter massively funded ads complex developed by best software minds of generation. Google is winning only because most of the folks are non-tech,  just use gadgets and  don't bother about privacy and ads protection

Comment: @vatosarmat Totally - a David vs Goliath scenario for the 21st century. Check out the comment blocker as well - never read the comments..... (LOL)

Comment: Nice to see I'm not alone in using adblockers for hot network questions